# Safety copy of an Apache Cassandra database

Tags: database, cassandra

How can I create a safety copy (dump) from Cassandra. Is available any tool like `mysqldump`?
Maybe there is a way to make something like an ISO image from database?

Answer (score 3):

See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Backing_up_data

You can use snapshots, or export the data to JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

The `COPY` command also could help: [Simple data importing and exporting with Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra)